# What is basic requiremnt to publish ads on site?

Tags: google-adsense

I applied to google adsence last week. But they had rejected my application since they found some contents on my site which were not matching to their policies.
I was surprised since no content on my site was spreading voilence, vulgarity. And all the articles on the site were written by myself.
One of my friend suggested that

1. the domain must be 6 months old.
2. Average daily hits must be 30
   hits/day.

is there any other requiremnt?

Comment: neither of those things are a requirement for adsense. I've used it on brand new sites before, with new domains and basically no traffic

Comment: If it's article-stack.com (from your profile), it may be the articles that talk about "hacking".

Comment: If google really analyze contents then they must found that all hacking articles are harmless. They can not cause any security issue. And they are written to improve security issues. They must read them instead of using some silly algos

Answer (score 2):

You've overlooked the most obvious one: content (just like Google said). Something about your content is not appropriate as per Google's guidelines which is far more in depth then just "violence and vulgarity":

> Publishers may not place AdSense code
> on pages with content that violates
> any of our content guidelines. Some
> examples include content that is
> adult, violent or advocating racial
> intolerance.
>
> Sites with Google ads may
> not include or link to:
>
> - Pornography, adult or mature content
> - Violent content
> - Content related to racial intolerance or advocacy against any
>   individual, group or organisation
> - Excessive profanity
> - Hacking/cracking content
> - Gambling or casino-related content
> - Illicit drugs and drug paraphernalia content
> - Sales of beer or hard alcohol
> - Sales of tobacco or tobacco-related products
> - Sales of prescription drugs
> - Sales of weapons or ammunition (e.g. firearms, firearm components, fighting
>   knives, stun guns)
> - Sales of products that are replicas or imitations of designer goods
> - Sales or distribution of coursework or student essays
> - Content regarding programs which compensate users for clicking ads or
>   offers, performing searches, surfing
>   websites or reading emails
> - Any other content that is illegal, promotes illegal activity or infringes
>   on the legal rights of others
>
> Publishers are also not permitted to
> place AdSense code on pages with
> content primarily in an unsupported
> language.

If you are unsure what content may be causing the issue edit your question and include your link. We'll see if we can spot it for you.

Comment: John!! I hope you had seen some of articles on my site. You'll find that all of them will pass above criteria. Moreover, I dont feel hacking is bad term while cracking is.

Comment: One of the article for your reference http://article-stack.com/featured/5-efficient-ways-to-hack-locked-folders.amty

Answer (score 1):

articlestack, using the comment/response to John Conde's reply where you use this article as an example:

http://article-stack.com/featured/5-efficient-ways-to-hack-locked-folders.amty

The following is in your examples meta data

```
<meta name='description' content='Hack PC security in multiple ways. open any locked folder in some minutes without knowing password' />
<meta name='keywords' content='pc security hack, unlock folder, crack, beginner, non-technical guide' />
```

I would argue the keywords alone clearly breach the "Hacking/cracking content" John mentions.

Edit - if it helps John's post was taken from here: https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182

Comment: i dont have patient to read google plolicies. But i'll edit the meta tag as per your suggestion. And'll remove crack word from their.

Comment: You have numerous references to hacking in your meta data, and in the article itself, for example: "Congrats!! You have become a hacker" I don't think removing the word "crack" from keywords will be enough.

Comment: it looks dramaticle, but `site:article-stack.com crack` returned zero results.

Comment: The adwords policy clearly states "Publishers may not place AdSense code on pages with content that violates any of our content guidelines." You have pages on your site about hacking/cracking.  Your content violates the guidelines, therefore you can't display adwords on your website. If you want adwords on your site, remove all the hacking/cracking pages entirely. Don't try and trick google by removing/altering individual words, google will win.