# Google Adsense is not responding

Tags: google-adsense

When I applied for google adsense they replied me on the same day (Unfortunately they rejected my application. And asked me to resubmit)

I resumitted the application for adsense around 8-10 days ago. Still it is pending from their end. Does any one has idea how much maximum time they can take?

Comment: What did they give as the reason they rejected your site? And what did you do to resolve that problem?

Comment: they hadnt mentioned any reason. They just replied that some contents on my site are conflicting their policies. I just removed 2-3 articles from my site that were doubtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to say exactly. Make sure you double check their terms and conditions in case there is some small thing you missed.

The only thing I can see that may cause problems is sponsor section on the right. Although you do not have any in there at the moment, maybe it's not clear you would remove this if you installed Adsense.

Several ad networks are fussy about what other adverts can be used in conjunction with their ads. I would say remove that section for now, wait a few days and try again.

Comment: ok i'll do it soon

Comment: Finally they had accepted my application after a long wait around 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I [commented](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/what-is-basic-requiremnt-to-publish-ads-on-site) 2 weeks ago that you had articles about hacking and cracking on your website. You've removed some of them, [but not all](http://article-stack.com/education/web-design-n-development/blog-blogger-blogging/i-hacked-admin-section-of-my-site-yesterday-morning.amty).

If you were flagged for hacking/cracking content, it is almost certain that google will check that you have taken appropriate action, that means removing **everything** to do with hacking.

Comment: rest of the articles doesnt contain any inproper word in their meta tags as well as on page. They all are related to tip & trick. hacking is a good word not bad. Many sites use it. this time they hadn't rejected even

Comment: I understand the term "hacking" doesn't necessarily mean bad, but your article entitled "I hacked the admin section of my website" is almost certainly not "good" hacking either.